# How i can disable "Create pull request" button for users in AWS CodeCommit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I have two groups in AWS CodeCommit. One for `Admin` and one for `Developers`.
I want to restrict that only admin can create pull request from develop to master branch, and from master to develop. But i want to allow all developers to make pull request from feature branches to develop branch. Any idea?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an IAM role or policy to deny this action. See [codecommit:CreatePullRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/auth-and-access-control-permissions-reference.html#aa-pr) and [Creating policy guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_create.html). For restricting pull requests for a specific branches, you can add a `Condition` to the policy, see example here in section [Create a conditional policy in IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/refining-access-to-branches-in-aws-codecommit/).